# Is it possible to intercept the assignment to local variable in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

Or, in Python speak, the binding of a local name? I.e.

```
def foo(x):
    y = x+1
    ...
```

Is it possible to detect that y is being changed in the second line? Is there some dict in foo that stores locals?

Comment: Detect *from where*? What are you trying to achieve? There is `locals()`, which may help.

Comment: Well, foo is an object. I was thinking maybe i could override something called upon assignment

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11024646/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/12274157/3001761